# Prime ideal in $k[X,Y]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Consider a prime ideal $I=(f_1, f_2,...,f_m)$ in $k[X_1,X_2,...,X_s]$ and prime ideal $J=(g_1,g_2,..,g_n)$ in $k[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_v]$.

So here is my question is it true that:

> $H=(f_1, f_2,...,f_m,g_1,g_2,..,g_n)$ in the ring 
>   $k[X_1,X_2,...,X_s,Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_v]$ is prime ideal.

If $k$ is algebraically closed field then $V(H)=V(I)\times V(J)$ is product of two irreducible varieties so $V(H)$ is irreducible and $H$ actually be prime ideal. Therefore my question is asked for arbitrary field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false: take $k=\mathbf Q$, and the prime ideals $(X^2-2)\subset \mathbf Q[X]$, $(Y^2-2)\subset \mathbf Q[Y]$. By the third isomorphism theorem,
\begin{align}\mathbf Q[X,Y]/(X^2-2,Y^2-2)\!&\simeq\!\mathbf Q[X,Y]/(X^2-2)\!\!\Bigm/\!\!(X^2-2,Y^2-2)/(X^2-2)\!\simeq\!\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)[Y]/(Y^2-2)\\&
\simeq\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)[Y]/(Y-\sqrt2)\times \mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)[Y]/(Y-\sqrt2)\!\simeq\!\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)\times\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)\end{align}